# Failed to render a d3js object in Reactjs: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_groups, _parents})

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3js with ReactJs. I'm not sure how to write the render function :/ can someone help please? I tried to render {circleAttributes} but it returns an error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_groups, _parents}).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { select } from 'd3-selection'

class StartAgain extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.svgExample = this.svgExample.bind(this)
  }

  svgExample(){
    var jsonCircles = [
      { "x_axis": 30, "y_axis": 30, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
      { "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple"},
      { "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color" : "red"}];

    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 200)
                        .attr("height", 200);

    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(jsonCircles)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle");

    var circleAttributes = circles
                         .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                         .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                         .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                         .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
  }

  render() {
        return (<svg width="500" height="500">
                  {?????}
                </svg>)
    }
}

export default StartAgain
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your d3 selector is selecting body, instead it should be within scope of component. I suggest you to do something like this.

Secondly you have to make sure that your component is rendered before you call d3 functions on dom.

Thirdly you are not calling function for svgExample anywhere.

Try this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { select } from 'd3-selection'

class StartAgain extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.svgExample = this.svgExample.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.svgExample();
  }

  svgExample(){
    var jsonCircles = [
      { "x_axis": 30, "y_axis": 30, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
      { "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple"},
      { "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color" : "red"}];

    var svgContainer = d3.select(this.container).append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 200)
                        .attr("height", 200);

    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(jsonCircles)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle");

    var circleAttributes = circles
                         .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                         .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                         .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                         .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
  }

  render() {
        return <div ref={cont => this.container = cont} style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px' }} />
    }
}

export default StartAgain
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree that this example is MUCH better. However, I would also suggest to NOT use ids in render() and instead use refs. So something like `<div ref={e => this.div = e}` and then use use d3 like this: `d3.select(this.div)`.

Comment: Yes agreed, will change the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MarioNikolaus . Can you explain how `ref={cont => this.container = cont}` is working ?

Comment: @Birish Well in newer versions of React ref is callback function with element as parameter. So all you do is really bind that element to component scope. Cont here is parameter in callback and a reference to an element and `this.container = cont` is just adding that element in component scope so that you can reference it throughout your component.